# Is there a way to re-create a virtual machine using existing files?

Tags: virtualbox

I accidentally uninstalled virtualBox, and I'm wondering if there is a way to re-create the virtual machine that I had on my re-installed virtualBox. All the files are still here (.vbox, .vmdk and all the snapshots and logs)

I am quite new to virtualBox, so sorry if this question seems stupid.

The Virtual Machine I am trying to run is Ubuntu.

Comment: First backup or move the entire folder of that old VM. Reinstall VBox and Google this "import vmdk in virtualbox".

Comment: You need to indicated what operating system you have Virtual Box installed on.  You should edit your question, instead of submitting a coment, to include this vital information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can quite easily.

1. Reinstall VirtualBox.
2. Go to the "Machine" menu
3. Click "Add"
4. Navigate to where your VM was originally saved.
5. Click "Open"

Note:

- For Windows OS: By default, if you didn't change the path, it will be in your "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\VirtualBox VMs" folder .
- For Linux, it should be in your home directory with the same folder name.

More details here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97728_01/F12469/html/vboxconfigdata.html